# Tracking goals on AJAX calls in Google Analytics

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-analytics

On my website the goal that I want to track is actually attached to an AJAX call rather than a specific URL. Is there anyway to track that in Google Analytics?

Note: I am using JQuery.

The only solution that I can think of at the moment is having a tiny iFrame somewhere on the page and loading the Goal URL into that frame. However, that doesn't sound clean and it will also mess with my pageviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at Google Analytics [event tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html)?  I've used it before for AJAX based comments with some success.

On your page you would then use something similar to the following to track the URL in Google Analytics:

```
<input type='button' onClick="javascript:pageTracker._trackPageview('/goal/comment.html') />
```

Comment: That looks good but it would mess with the pageview counts a bit I suppose. I guess I just have to live with that...  I was hoping for some way to trigger the goal directly...

Comment: What you've shown isn't actually 'Event Tracking'--the significance being that these 'clicks' won't show up in GA under 'Events' but rather as PageViews (so e.g., you can just create a new profile filtered to include *only* these 'clicks', then filter them out of your main profile since they aren't real PageViews).

Comment: OK, perhaps calling it 'Event Tracking' was the wrong term, although that does exist.  In my example, the URL in the _trackPageview call can be anything you want, the page doesn't have to actually exist.  You could then base your goal parameters off of that custom URL so that it doesn't change your pageviews for another part of the site.  For instance, on the site where I use the above code, the /goal/comment.html file doesn't exist, therefore I know that hits to that URL came from the click action on my page.